# combobox city and state

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, sqlite

I have 2 tables with name = city and state

city

```
id_city |  name_city         
   1    |   JED
   2    |   RUD
   3    |   DMM
```

state

```
id_state  |  id_for_city | name_state
     1    |      1       | JED1
     2    |      1       | JED2
     3    |      2       | RUD1
     4    |      2       | RUD2
```

I used ComboBox and i have 2

combobox1

```
public void Filecombo() {
    try {
        String sql = "select name_city from  city";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            options.add(rs.getString("name_city"));
        }
        comboCity.setItems(options);
        pstmt.close();
        rs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

second comboBox2

```
public void Filecombo2() {

    try {

        String sq2 = " select * from state,city where state.id_for_city= city.id_city";

        pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(sq2);

        rs = pstmt2.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {

            options2.add(rs.getString("name_state"));

        }

        comboBranch.setItems(options2);
        pstmt.close();
        rs.close();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
```

when i select combobox1 it will appear all city 
but when i select combobox2 not value apear 
i don't know what is problem i think  `String sq2`  code is wrong ?
and give to me error in java when run program

Comment: what database are you using ? Please tag accordingly

Comment: i'm using sqlite studio

Comment: The important part of your question "give to me error in java". What is the error message? Without that piece we are left guessing.

Comment: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such column: state.id_for_city)

Comment: String sq2 = " select * from state,city where state.id_for_city= city.id_city";
is working in sql but in java it given to me error :C or code is wrong ? i don't know

Comment: For starters you should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. Time to stop using comma separated table names. Do you really have a column named "id_for_city" in your state table? That seems totally backwards. Your state shouldn't have anything related to a city. Your city should have a relation to the state.

Comment: yah sorry between city and state 
but about problem  we can solve by using  ANSI-92 style joins?

Comment: What is the problem: the combo or the database? Please separate them out and then provide one [mcve] with the appropriate tags that demonstrates the problems, respectively

Comment: @kleopatra is working in database but in combo give to me error
i think problem in code ,i had tried but i don't know what code is true